# Is there faster way than looping to run a python function on multiple files?

Tags: linux

I am trying to run a python function on 100s of files using a for loop as follows. It seems like the process is very slow.  I was wondering if there is a way to make the process faster as I am using HPC computers with GPU.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FILES="/directory_with_files/*.ply"
for i in $FILES; 
do python3 function.py -file $i --odir /output_directory --verbose; done
```

Comment: This won't affect your speed, but you have a couple of bad practices there: i) don't use CAPS for your variable names in shell/bash scripts since by convention, global environment variables are capitalized and if your variables are also in caps that can lead to naming collisions and weird bugs; ii) you are not quoting your variable which opens you to [other dangers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222), but you don't even need the variable here: `for i in /directory_with_files/*.ply` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

A GPU won't help you unless the program itself already utilizes it, but my go-to tool for this is [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). It has many flags but I guess your command would be something like this:

```
$ find /directory_with_files -name '*.ply' | parallel "python3 function.py -file {} --odir /output_directory --verbose"
```

It will run as many jobs in parallel as it deems proper, which should be one per core by default.

[Rumour has it](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#remote-execution) that it should be possible to run remote jobs using this over SSH as well, but I have never tried it.